# How to filter negative and positive returns by weekday in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I need to either create a for loop or a list comprehension to filter out negative returns and positive returns by weekday.

I’m using a csv file of a stock ticker from yahoo finance. There is a column “weekday” and a column for “return”. What basic loop or list comprehension can I use?

I am using pandas but can do something without and not using numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your df looks like this

```
  weekday   return
0       M        1
1       W       -3
2       F        4
3       T        5
4       W       -3
5       F       -2
6       M       -4
```

you can filter by weekday and negative return by

```
df[(df['weekday'] == 'M') & (df['return'] < 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! So this is telling me empty data frame. What am I missing ? 

kelya[(kelya[‘Weekday’] == ‘Monday’) & (kelya[‘Return’]<0)]

Comment: It's hard to say without any reproducible data. Can you update your question to include a portion of your dataframe?